# After remove if php extension

Tags: php, html

Why when I remove php extension then php not working. What's it solution?

Comment: Dont change the question to a compleatly new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set a password in the same query where you confirm an email:

```
$con->query("UPDATE users SET isEmailConfirmed=1, token='', Password='{$hashedPassword}' WHERE Email_ID='$email' ");
```

Comment: Did you get any error messages? enable error_reporting(-1); if you don't do it before.